# Mounting old cyrillic HFS partition in modern Linux

Tags: mount, partition, filenames, character-encoding

I'm looking for an easiest way to transfer files to my old Macintosh LCII (to avoid messing with floppies or CD burning). I figured that I can probably get its old SCSI harddrive to mount on my modern Arch Linux machine, and sure, that seems to be the case.
However, it has a Russian version of System 7 along with quite a lot of MacCyrillic-encoded filenames.

I do understand that I have to pass a parameter to the `mount` command, specifying the codepage in order to make cyrillic filenames show up properly. My problem is that I just can't figure how that codepage is called. I've tried obvious suggestions like 10007, CP10007, x-mac-cyrillic, mac-cyrillic, and it doesn't accept any of those.

Does anyone know how that codepage is called? Is it actually supported anywhere anymore? Maybe I can somehow get a list of all supported codepages I can use with the `mount` command (I haven't figured that one either yet, if it's possible at all)?

I guess if I'll make an external HDD just for file transfer, I can live without cyrillic names, but now I'm genuinely curious.